# JAXB - while unmarshalling code breaks due to extra tags in xml. Need to write code so that even if extra xml tags comes it should not break

Tags: jaxb

I am marshelling xml to some java object which as some basic properties along with @XMLTransient private Collection ignoreTags but when extra tags comes in the xml code breaks during unmarshling. I want to write bullet proof code so that even if extra tag comes it should not break.

Comment: You can't really do this with JAXB. While it is in principle possible with `@XmlAnyElement` and co., this entirely defeats JAXB idea and purpose of mapping XML to strongly structured Java models.

Comment: If you post a few example, wa might have some ideas.